# Is there a way to remove hallowed ground?

Tags: terraria

I want, for aesthetic and security reasons, to keep the Hallowed biome out of my village. Problem is, before I managed to stop it, it had already spread quite a bit, so I'm searching for a way to quickly remove it.

I don't want to have to go trough each patch of grass and to remove the hallowed grass, and the purification powder don't work on it. Is there another way?

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll not only have to remove the grass, but the pearlstone and pearlsand as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sprinkling vile powder or throwing unholy water will remove hallow. You can make vile powder from vile mushrooms at an alchemy station or purchase it from the dryad during a blood moon. Unholy water is crafted from a bottled water, an ebonsand block, and corrupt seeds. Note that unholy water will not just remove the hallow but **replace it with corruption**.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Fambida](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7992/fambida)'s solution, you can now use the [Clentaminator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clentaminator) to purify Hallowed ground. Using green solution will turn the ground back to normal while other solutions may have some more interesting effects.

Answer (score -1):

Using Vile Powder/Viscous Powder Or Unholy/Blood Water in combination with purification powder will give the desired results.